# addProximityAlert works initially

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-location

I create a number of ProximityAlerts. It seems only the first works and sometime the second. They also seem to expire. I call this method to create a ProximityAlert:

```
public boolean addProximityAlert(int id) {

  locationManager.addProximityAlert(
    latitude,
    longitude,
    POINT_RADIUS,             
    PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION,      
    getPendingIntent(id)    
  );

  registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), getIntentFilter(id));

  return true;
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(int id) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + id);
  intent.setAction(String.valueOf(id));
  return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}

private IntentFilter getIntentFilter(int id) {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + id);
    filter.addAction(String.valueOf(id));
    return filter;
}
```

In ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (entering) {
        message = context.getString(R.string.notification_alert_entering);
    } else {
        message = context.getString(R.string.notification_alert_exiting);
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification notification = createNotification();
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, context.getString(R.string.notification_alert), message, pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

Variables:

```
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE = 1;    // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE = 1000;       // in Milliseconds
private static final long POINT_RADIUS = 500;                       // in Meters
private static final long PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION = -1;
private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.xxx.yyy.ProximityAlert";
```

I'd like to create a number of unique alerts and then get notified each time when entering or exiting the proximity (can happen multiple times). All the alerts should stay valid, can someone please point me in the right direction why this is not working properly?

Comment: How are you testing? Did you check whether alert comes on entering/exiting POINT_RADIUS to actual lat/long position? The alert will only come while crossing the POINT_RADIUS.

Comment: @Shrikant Updated question. I test with a real device and move in and out from the location. Ie. create an alert, drive my car 2km and then drive back to location.

Comment: Did you also had a good internet connection? Because your code looks good to me. I have also done the same way and it works very well(i get alert on almost exact location). Try reducing MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE (for testing set it to 0)

Comment: Did not get it working reliable. It seems to work a few times only locally. Travel away from the geo point a few kilometer and then coming back does not trigger the pending Intent again? Can someone spot some error in code or other problem?

Comment: Actually my code worked, the problem was one need to add the proximity alert and broadcast recievers after a boot or exit of your Activity the broadcast receivers. I used a service to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have added proximity:

```
String geo = "geo:" + storeProximityData.getLatitude() + ","
                    + storeProximityData.getLongitude();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(PROXIMITY_ALERT_HOME, Uri.parse(geo));
            PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    sContext.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            sLocationManager.addProximityAlert(
                    storeProximityData.getLatitude(), // the
                    // latitude
                    // of
                    // the
                    // central
                    // point
                    // of
                    // the alert region
                    storeProximityData.getLongitude(), // the longitude of
                                                        // the
                                                        // central point of
                                                        // the
                                                        // alert
                    // region
                    storeProximityData.getRadius(), // the radius of the
                                                    // central
                                                    // point of the
                                                    // alert
                                                    // region, in
                    // meters
                    expirationTime, // time for this proximity alert, in
                    // milliseconds, or -1 to
                    // indicate no expiration
                    proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to
                                    // fire
                    // when entry to or exit from the alert region
                    // is detected
                    );
```

And This is how I register the receiver:

```
private static String PROXIMITY_ALERT_HOME = "path.to.ProximityAlert";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_ALERT_HOME);
            filter.addDataScheme("geo");
            sContext.registerReceiver(
                    new ProximityResponderBroadcastReceiver(), filter);
```

Comment: It seems addProximityAlert is not reliable. Not sure if my code is wrong?

Comment: This code works for me almost all the time. But the docs also says its not works for almost everytime. There might be some other issue. The docs says: Due to the approximate nature of position estimation, if the device passes through the given area briefly, it is possible that no Intent will be fired. Similarly, an Intent could be fired if the device passes very close to the given area but does not actually enter it. Courtesy: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double, double, float, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: Actually my code worked, the problem was one need to add the proximity alert and broadcast recievers after a boot or exit of your Activity the broadcast receivers. I used a service to handle it.

Comment: Yeah that's right.. This is how it should be. You need to add broadcast receiver to capture the BootComplete intent, and on receiving the intent, check if you need to start the proximity...